# PHP Valid Date Format

Tags: php

I've been trying to read the PHP documentation for my answer.

Why does PHP recognize that `04/06/2020` is in `MM/DD/YYYY` format and not `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Looking at the docs that is because it is simply not an accepted format. With that being the case I suppose there would never be a case where PHP would confuse this format with another?

Is there a way to amend to following so that I could tell `strtotime()` the input date format (maybe completely unnecessary)?

```
$date = "04/06/2020";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Why? Because apparently mostly Americans use MM/DD/YYYY, while Europeans use DD-MM-YYYY (I'm guessing from the [reasoning in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)).  As it mentions, you can try using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` instead.

Comment: @aynber thank you for the answer and alternative solution. If you put this as an answer I will accept it.